# Winston MongoDB: How to pipe logs to many collections, instead all goes to one collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, logging, winston

How to make winston-mongodb logs to different collections at the same time

```
var winston = require('winston');
require('winston-mongodb').MongoDB;


var logger = new winston.Logger({
  level: 'info',
  transports: [
    new(winston.transports.MongoDB)({
            db : 'mongodb://xxxx'
        })
  ],
  capped : true,  // defaults to false
})
```

This one logs everything to the default collection `log`, but I need to make a collection to each module, so I know where to investigate certain problem for a specific domain

Answer (score 1):

Simple and straight forward, we can channel logs to as many collections as we want:

```
winston.loggers.add('mongoLog',{
    transports : [
        new(winston.transports.MongoDB)({
            db : 'mongodb://xxxxx',',
            collection : 'collection1',
            level : 'info',
            capped : true
        }),
    ]
});

var mongoLog = winston.loggers.get('mongoLog')
mongoLog.info('hello') 


winston.loggers.add('profileLog',{
    transports : [
        new(winston.transports.MongoDB)({
            db : 'mongodb://xxxxx',
            collection : 'collection2',
            level : 'info',
            capped : true
        }),
    ]
});

var profileLog = winston.loggers.get('profileLog')
profileLog.error('user profile is not valid')
```

Comment: Could you please help me to answer this question about winston logger?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511857/cappedmax-not-working-in-winston-mongodb-logger-in-node-js-on-ubuntu

Comment: can you tell me a method to delete or move the old logs when size of collection reaches to certain limit?