# cappedMax not working in winston-mongodb logger in Node.js on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, logging, winston

I have created a logger in Node.js using the winston module and added MongoDB transport by requiring winston-mongodb module with the following options:

```
{
  db: config.db[k.DB_ENV.AUTHOR],
  username: config.dbUser,
  password: config.dbPassword,
  collection: 'log-aggregation',
  storeHost: true,
  capped: true,
  cappedMax: 10 // documents
}
```

I expect the logger to create a **new collection for every 10 documents**. But the logger continue logging in the **same** collection. I commented the `collection: 'log-aggregation'` line to check if the options are really working and then it began to log to the default `'log'` collection.

So where is my mistake? Is there a minimum no of document size to the `cappedMax` option? I tried this with `cappedSize` option also with 10 to 1000 values, still the new collections are not created.

I want to know the minimum and maximum permissible value for cappedSize and cappedMax option?

I also want to know what will be the name of new collections created?

Comment: regarding the collection name, you specify it here --> `collection: 'log-aggregation'`. for `cappedSize` I'm not sure why it keeps storing more than the specified size, but maybe you can try `cappedSize` and add a number in bytes

Comment: @securecurve I tried cappedSize in bytes and cappedMax too..still no new collections are created

Comment: As far as I understood, `capped` is just creating a capped MongoDB collection (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) which work in a way similar to circular buffers. It's not creating a new collection if the previous one is "full".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use to get multiple logs:

```
var winston = require('winston');
require('winston-mongodb').MongoDB;


winston.loggers.add('userLog',{
    transports : [
        new(winston.transports.MongoDB)({
            db : 'mongodb://username:password.mongolab.com:5555/log_db',
            collection : 'userLog',
            capped : true
        }),
    ]
});
winston.loggers.add('profileLog',{
    transports : [
        new(winston.transports.MongoDB)({
            db : 'mongodb://username:password.mongolab.com:5555/log_db',                collection : 'profileLog',
            capped : true
        }),
    ]
});
```

And it works fine with no observable latency.

P.S. You can add all the options you want after or before `capped:true`

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

So just to confirm that the 'capped' features of winston-mongodb which are:

```
capped:       // true or false
cappedMax:    // [int] number of documents per collection
cappedSize:    // [byte-size] Size of documents capped per collection in bytes
```

ARE WORKING but it is important to note that in order for it to work you can not modify and existing collection with these properties. It is assumed that you are starting from scratch. For example if you have already created your collection and now wish to add capped features to it THEN THIS WILL NOT WORK!

You will need to completely dump the collection within the database and start from scratch or alternative just create a new collection.

For example this is an extract of code from my transports array.

```
new transports.MongoDB({
          level: 'error',
          db: process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_LOG_STRING,
          options: { useUnifiedTopology: true },
          format: combine(timestamp(), json()),
          collection: 'prod_log',
          capped: true,
          cappedMax: 2
        })
```

So at present I made sure that this collection does not exists in my database, what this config will do is only allow 2 documents at anyone time to be stored in my collection, and any future errors will overwrite any existing ones so you will only every have the last two 'error' logs/documents in the collection.

Being playing around with this for sometime, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I fixed it by simply updating the winston-mongodb version
npm i winston-mongodb